# How to call Parse Cloud Code functions from my Android application?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have already uploaded the function on parse using parse deploy command and i have a data class named Review along with few entries which is displaying in my Parse Core Dashboard.Here is my cloud code function:

```
            Parse.Cloud.define("averageStars", function(request, response) {
              var query = new Parse.Query("Review");
              query.equalTo("movie", request.params.movie);
              query.find({
                success: function(results) {
                  var sum = 0;
                  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
                    sum += results[i].get("stars");
                  }
                  response.success(sum / results.length);
                },
                error: function() {
                  response.error("movie lookup failed");
                }
              });
            });
```

Here is my Android Function:

```
            HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    params.put("movie", "The Matrix");
                    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("averageStars", params, new FunctionCallback<Float>() {
                       public void done(Float ratings, ParseException e) {
                          //done action
                       }
                    });
```

This is what i am getting in the log:

```
 NO RESPONSE:ParseRequestException: invalid session token
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try including `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` in your cloud code function. Also make sure that you have correctly implemented logging in the user from which the cloud function is called.